# How to get Tabulator rownum formatter to run after adding rows to tableData with reactiveData option?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using a Tabulator table with the reactiveData option enabled. When I add rows to the table, the row number column, using the "rownum" formatter, shows "0" for all rows until I click on the sort button in the column header. Then it'll correctly display row numbers. I suspect that it might be something to do with underlying array not triggering the right event to trigger the rownum formatter when a row is updated/added/deleted. How can I get this to show the right row number when the rows are added to the table without requiring the end user to click on the sort button?

The column in question:
`{title:"#", field:"rowNumber", formatter:"rownum", visible:true, download:false},`

Expected: each row should have the row number in this column.

Result: each row has a "0" in this column until the sort button in the column header is clicked.

Edit: I've determined that each row has a "position" value of 0 prior to clicking the sort button. According to the [docs](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/components#component-row), position is supposed to start at 1. So it seems like position is not being updated correctly somewhere.